# SQL Server merge datetime rows in one row and splits when values of other columns change

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to create a view in SQL which merge start datetime and last datetime and splits when value column changed knowing that the value of the date difference is not fixed. For example I have a table name Sensors:

| SensorID | StartTime | EndTime | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 14033 | 2023-05-01 00:00:00.000 | 2023-05-01 00:05:00.000 | 0 |
| 14033 | 2023-05-01 00:05:00.000 | 2023-05-01 00:20:00.000 | 1 |
| 14033 | 2023-05-01 00:20:00.000 | 2023-05-01 03:00:00.000 | 1 |
| 14033 | 2023-05-01 03:00:00.000 | 2023-05-01 12:00:00.000 | 1 |
| 14033 | 2023-05-01 12:00:00.000 | 2023-05-01 20:00:00.000 | 0 |
| 14033 | 2023-05-01 20:00:00.000 | 2023-05-01 22:59:59.000 | 0 |

the result must be like the table below:

| SensorID | StartTime | EndTime | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 14033 | 2023-05-01 00:00:00.000 | 2023-05-01 00:05:00.000 | 0 |
| 14033 | 2023-05-01 00:05:00.000 | 2023-05-01 12:00:00.000 | 1 |
| 14033 | 2023-05-01 12:00:00.000 | 2023-05-01 22:59:59.000 | 0 |

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Base on this sample, here is some piece of code, inspired by Itzik Ben-Gan , Special Islands solution [here](https://sqlperformance.com/2018/09/t-sql-queries/special-islands) is the link.

(I added CTEs to be better understood)

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.vw_Sensors
AS

    with CTE_Source AS
    (
        SELECT *    ,
            LAG(EndTime,1,NULL) OVER(PARTITION BY SensorID ORDER BY StartTime) as EndTime_prev,
            LAG(Value,1,NULL) OVER(PARTITION BY SensorID ORDER BY StartTime) as Value_prev
        FROM dbo.Sensors
    )
    ,CTE_Source2 AS
    (
        SELECT * ,
            CASE WHEN s.StartTime <> ISNULL(s.EndTime_prev,'19000101') THEN 1
                 WHEN s.Value <> ISNULL(s.Value_prev,-1) THEN 1
                 ELSE 0 
            END as IsGrp
        FROM CTE_Source as s
    )
    ,CTE_Source3 AS
    (
        SELECT * ,
            SUM(s.isGrp) OVER(PARTITION BY s.SensorID  ORDER BY StartTime ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as sumGrp
        FROM CTE_Source2 as s
    )
    SELECT s.SensorID,
        MIN(s.StartTime) as StartTime,
        MAX(s.EndTime) as EndTime,
        MAX(s.Value) as Value
    FROM CTE_Source3 as s
    GROUP BY 
        s.SensorID,
        s.sumGrp
GO
```

output:

| SensorID | StartTime | EndTime | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 14033 | 2023-05-01 00:00:00.000 | 2023-05-01 00:05:00.000 | 0 |
| 14033 | 2023-05-01 00:05:00.000 | 2023-05-01 12:00:00.000 | 1 |
| 14033 | 2023-05-01 12:00:00.000 | 2023-05-01 22:59:59.000 | 0 |

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/PMzCpis0)

In step 1 (first `select`), we just calculate the previous values for `EndTime` and  for `Value`

| SensorID | StartTime | EndTime | value | EndTime_prev | Value_prev |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 14033 | 2023-05-01 00:00:00.000 | 2023-05-01 00:05:00.000 | 0 | *null* | *null* |
| 14033 | 2023-05-01 00:05:00.000 | 2023-05-01 00:20:00.000 | 1 | 2023-05-01 00:05:00.000 | 0 |
| 14033 | 2023-05-01 00:20:00.000 | 2023-05-01 03:00:00.000 | 1 | 2023-05-01 00:20:00.000 | 1 |

The step 2, if there is a difference between `StartTime` and `previous EndTime` or a difference between `Value` and `previous Value` , then we mark this row as `1 = IsGrp`

| SensorID | StartTime | EndTime | value | EndTime_prev | Value_prev | IsGrp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 14033 | 2023-05-01 00:00:00.000 | 2023-05-01 00:05:00.000 | 0 | *null* | *null* | 1 |
| 14033 | 2023-05-01 00:05:00.000 | 2023-05-01 00:20:00.000 | 1 | 2023-05-01 00:05:00.000 | 0 | 1 |
| 14033 | 2023-05-01 00:20:00.000 | 2023-05-01 03:00:00.000 | 1 | 2023-05-01 00:20:00.000 | 1 | 0 |

In the step 3, we apply `SUM` on this new field (isGrp) .

| SensorID | StartTime | EndTime | value | EndTime_prev | Value_prev | IsGrp | sumGrp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 14033 | 2023-05-01 00:00:00.000 | 2023-05-01 00:05:00.000 | 0 | *null* | *null* | 1 | 1 |
| 14033 | 2023-05-01 00:05:00.000 | 2023-05-01 00:20:00.000 | 1 | 2023-05-01 00:05:00.000 | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| 14033 | 2023-05-01 00:20:00.000 | 2023-05-01 03:00:00.000 | 1 | 2023-05-01 00:20:00.000 | 1 | 0 | 2 |
| 14033 | 2023-05-01 03:00:00.000 | 2023-05-01 12:00:00.000 | 1 | 2023-05-01 03:00:00.000 | 1 | 0 | 2 |

The final step/select is just to aggregate these information to display the desired output

Comment: Thank you Sabin for answering the question. It works fine. I will test more the function and if there is an issue I will reply here.

Comment: @MohammadNajem, great, glad to help!